# Mongo find Document after Insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

i use sails js 0.12.14 with mongodb. if i try to get a document after insert the document the document is empty

```
Products.create(product).exec(function(err, createdProduct) {
    Products.find({_id : createdProduct.id}).exec(function(err, foundProductAfterCreate) {
        console.log(foundProductAfterCreate);
    })});
```

Can anybody explain why the document is not available?

Update:
This is the correct code for me...

```
Products.create(product).exec(function(err, createdProduct) {
    Products.find({_id : createdProduct[0].id}).exec(function(err, foundProductAfterCreate) {
        console.log(foundProductAfterCreate);
    })});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `_id : createdProduct._id`

Comment: Also check the value returned by createdProduct...

Answer (score 2):

The doc you are querying for is literally the same one you already have

```
Products.create(product).exec(function(err, createdProduct) {
    // handle the error...
    console.log(createdProduct); // the full record
});
```

`createdProduct` is exactly the same object you would get if you queried by id.

If you *do* ever need to query by id, sails does a fairly comprehensive switch from `_id` which is the mongo standard, to `id` with no underscore. You would do that like this:

```
Products.findOne({id: createdProduct[0].id}).exec(function(err, foundAgain) { // etc
```

...no underscores anywhere unless you use `.native` for more basic mongo query access.